# How to calculate number of elements that have a particular order in a permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm doing problems to practice for my abstract algebra final, and I came across this problem:

**Consider the following groups $ \mathbb{Z}_{3}^{4}$ and $S_{6}$. Which has more elements of order 3?**

I know that $ \mathbb{Z}_{3}^{4}$ has order |81| and every element except the identity has order |3|. Thus, 81 - 1 = 80 elements of order |3|.

For $S_{6}$, the elements of order |3| are represents as $({a}_{1}{a}_{2}{a}_{3})({a}_{4}{a}_{5}{a}_{6})$ and $({a}_{1}{a}_{2}{a}_{3})({a}_{4})({a}_{5})({a}_{6})$.

It is this part where I need to calculate the number of elements of order |3| in $S_{6}$ that I don't really know how to proceed. Is there a quick way to calculate it or an intuitive way?

Thank you,

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}_3^4$ you're right. For $S_6$, you know there are two kinds of possible elements. How many triplets $(a_1 a_2 a_3)$ are in $S^6$? (Hint: find the number of elements  $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6^3$ and divide by $3$ since each element can be represented in three ways)

Comment: @Marcos So,  I did 4*5*6 = 120(which is the number of possibilities?), then I did 120*2 = 240(as every triplets have two possible form $({a}_{1}{a}_{2}{a}_{3})$ and  $({a}_{1}{a}_{3}{a}_{2})$. Then, I divide by 3, 240/3 = 80(I don't understand this part).

Comment: You have $120$ possibilities of $(a_1a_2a_3)$, but since $(a_1 a_2 a_3)=(a_2 a_3 a_1)=(a_3 a_1 a_2)$ this implies that there are $120/3=40$. Do you understand this?

Comment: Yes, I understand this.

Comment: Can finish the exercise at this point? It is just one line.